# How to update/delete on a nested recordsets in php mysql with a checkbox?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have a nested recordsets namely questions and answers and a corresponsing checkbox foe each question. How can I update or delete records on the selected checkboxes only?

here is my code:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_iexam, $iexam);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM exam_questions WHERE question_exam_id = '$exam_id'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $iexam) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

do { ?>
    <tr>
        <th width="170" scope="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"
                   value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['question_id']; ?>"/>
            Question:
        </th>
        <td colspan="2" scope="col">
            <input name="textfield" type="text"
                   value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['question_description']; ?>"
                   size="50"/></td>
        <td width="549" colspan="2" scope="col"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Answers:</td>
    <?php
    mysql_select_db($database_iexam, $iexam);
    $query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM exam_answers WHERE answer_question_set_id = '" . $row_Recordset1['question_id'] . "'";
    $Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $iexam) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Recordset2       = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
    $totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);

    do { ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="170">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input name="textfield2" type="text" size="20"
                       value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['answer_description']; ?>"/>
                <input
                    name="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['answer_question_set_id']; ?>"
                    type="radio"
                    value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['answer_iscorrect']; ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)); ?>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
    <div align="center">With selected:
        <input name="Update" type="submit" class="submit_btn2" value="Update"/>
        <input name="Delete" type="submit" class="submit_btn2" value="Remove"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Tabspacing.. It wont kill you

Comment: Please , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give more details ? You want to know what to do with checked checkboxes when the user submit the form to update your database ?
You should avoid using `do {} while ();` even more when there is a few HTML code in it, it's a pain to read